# Elastic search index capability?

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

We need a generic index where our properties are changing with every object. We need a fulltext search capability with a distributed system.

Could we index different objects in one generic index in elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, elasticsearch allows to index different documents on the same index using a single [dynamic mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-dynamic-mapping.html) or, if you have only few different types of documents, you can have multiple [mappings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html) on the same index.